# Complex residue at infinity of $f(z)=\frac{z^5}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinity, residue-calculus

I'm having trouble finding residue of the function

$$f(z)=\frac{z^5}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\large{z^2}}\right)}$$

at infinity.
Wolfram kindly informs that it is equal to $-\frac{7}{360}$ (and gives expansion). How do get that?
Infinity is the pole of $7$th order. It seems not possible to efficiently expand $f(z)$ or $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ without computers to look for coefficient. Or is it?
Is it possible there is some tricky curve such that I'll be able to integrate over it?
Thank you.

Update:

Silly me, it's so easy:

$$z^5=\left(a_7 z^7 + \ldots + a_0 + \frac{a_{-1}}{z} + \ldots\right)\left(\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{6z^6}+\frac{1}{120z^{10}}-\ldots\right)$$

By comparing I get:
$$\begin{align}
&a_{-1}-\frac{a_3}{6}+\frac{a_7}{120}=0\\
&a_3-\frac{a_7}{6}=0\\
&a_7=1\\
\end{align}$$

And I can easily find $a_{-1}$.

Thank you again, Enigma.

Comment: Take the taylor series of $\sin(z)$ and substitute in $\frac{1}{z^2}$. Then its just a simple computation by dividing, which will give you a Laurent expansion.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't brave enough to attempt something like this. Thank you! It helped.